# Determine if it is possible that the digits of $n^2$ are five different even digits.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $3$.

(a) Determine if it is possible that the digits of $n^2$ are five different even digits.

(b) Determine all $n$ such that the digits of $n^2$ are different odd digits.

---

(b) If $n$ is odd then $n = 2k+1$, then we have $n^2 = 4k^2 +4k+1$ and hence $n^2 = 1 \mod 4$. Thus we have $n = 1,3 \mod 4$.

Thus $n$ always ends in either of $1,3,5,7$ or $9$.

But in that case the digit in ten's place of $n^2$ is always even, hence no such $n$ is possible.

---

I am stuck with part (a). Any hints are welcome.

Comment: For $a$...have you tried a search?  Note:  I don't really understand what the rules are.  Do you mean $n^2$ must be $5$ digits long and the digits are all distinct and even?  Like $20468$ were it a perfect square?  If so, just search.

Comment: For (a) you could say any such number would be $\equiv 2+4+6+8+0 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ while squares are only $\equiv  0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: @Henry: That's a great solution – worthy of an answer, I'd say :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From comment:*

For (a) you could say any such number with the digits $2,4,6,8,0$ in some order

would be $\equiv 2+4+6+8+0 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

while squares are only $\equiv  0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: If the number has fewer than 5 digits then?

Comment: @user5210: It is possible, for example $8^2=64\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $78^2=6084\equiv 0 \pmod 3$